# Aligning This Menu Center is hard

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to align the menu in the middle of the page.
I tried putting it on a table. I also tried `text-align`.

```css
body {
  background-color: #727288;
}

.top-bar-2 {
  background-color: #2A0405;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  top: 90px;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 10;
}

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #2A0405;
  font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "sans-serif";
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: red;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-bar-2">
  <div class="navbar">
    <a href="#home">Home</a>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn">Sound</button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn">Videos</button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn">Recipes</button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please read [ask] and post actual details and info. Repeating the same sentence over ran over does not add more details. It also is not allowed to do that for the purpose of bypassing the minimum character amount. The next time provide your code as [repro]. Last but not least, you should read into how to program a navbar correctly. Use semantic tags such as `nav` and list the links in an unordered list either as `ul` or `menu`.

Answer (score 0):

For the `.navbar` class,

Try adding `display:flex;` & either of them below whichever suits your requirement.

```
justify-content: space-evenly;
```

or

```
justify-content: space-around;
```

or

```
justify-content: space-between;
```